# Can a standlone Mono-based DLL be called from Ruby?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dll, mono

I have a C# class library that contains some specialized mathematical functionality relating to raster processing (it uses some asynchronous techniques to spped up the processing).  I have a project that my client wants written using Ruby on Rails (RoR) on a Linux box, that can benefit from using this library (I'd rather not port it to Ruby or C++).

The first part of my question is:

Can a standalone Mono-based DLL be created from my C# DLL?  (By standalone I mean, the DLL can be utilized WITHOUT having mono installed (all required libraries would be included in the single DLL)?

And the second part, if the answer to part 1 is 'yes', can this standalone mono-based DLL be called from Ruby?

EDIT 11/22/2014

I have made a little progress possibly.  I have created a *.so file by using

```
mono --aot -O=all dlltest.dll
```

(Obviously I now have Mono installed on my Ubuntu test VM.)  This results in dlltest.so, which I then add a symbolic link for in /usr/lib.

The code for my test Ruby script is:

```
require 'ffi'

module CsharpTest
    extend FFI::Library
    ffi_lib 'dlltest.so'
    attach_function :Hello, [], :string
end

ret_str = CsharpTest.Hello()
puts ret_str
```

Note that my simple C# class is:

```
using Systems;
namespace DllTest
{
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static string Hello()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the test Ruby script (ruby test.rb) I get the following error:

> ....:in 'attach_function': Function 'Hello' not found in [dlltest.so] (FFI::NotFoundError)

Using 'nm -Ca dlltest.so' the available functions are listed.  One of them is '0000000000001010 t DllTest_MyClass_Hello'.  If I use this label as opposed to 'Hello' I get a similar error.

Also note that 'nm -D --defined-only dlltest.so' does not list any functions with 'Hello' in them.

I'm still not sure if I've on the right track, but is there anything more I can try?  Or is this approach a dead end?

Comment: No it can't, you need a runtime to use a .net DLL.

Comment: Doesn't Mono provide the runtime?  As I understand it, Mono basically spins up a VM to run the C# within. So I think the first part of my question is really asking, can the Mono-runtime be bundled with the compiled C#, rather than having Mono installed already on the system?

Comment: Yes mono provides the runtime, that's why it needs to be installed, it does not form part of the DLL, that just contains IL that the runtime then just in time compiles to native instructions.

Comment: But with Xamarin, how is the Mono runtime included for mobile devices on which the Mono-runtime is not installed? Presumably it is bundled with the application somehow.

Comment: Xamarin is different, it does not include the mono rumtime when creating apps for android and IOS, in fact there is no mono runtime for android and IOS. It ahead of time compiles native apps from source for these platforms.

Comment: OK - thanks, I wonder if they support compilation for Linux too (which I'm guessing is similar to Android)?  I'll check their forums...